# XSLT add attributes to processed nodes

Tags: xslt, saxon

this is sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"                       
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                       
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog                      
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd                       
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog">
  <changeSet id="1" author="a">
    <createTable tableName="TABLE1">
      <column>
      </column>
    </createTable>
  </changeSet>
  <changeSet id="1-1" author="a">
    <createSequence sequenceName="SEQ_TABLE1" />
  </changeSet>
  <changeSet id="4" author="A">
    <createTable tableName="TABLE4">
      <column>
      </column>
    </createTable>
  </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

this is template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"               xpath-default-namespace="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="coreTables"                  select="('TABLE1','TABLE2')"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::*)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="databaseChangeLog">
    <!-- CORE-->
    <xsl:comment>CORE TABLES</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="coreTablesVariable" select="changeSet[createTable/@tableName=$coreTables]"/>
    <xsl:comment>CORE SEQUENCES</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="coreSequencesVariable" select="changeSet[createSequence[starts-with(@sequenceName, 'SEQ_') and substring-after(@sequenceName, 'SEQ_') = $coreTables]]"/>
    <xsl:comment>CORE INDEXES</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="coreIndexesVariable" select="changeSet[createIndex/@tableName=$coreTables]"/>
    <xsl:comment>CORE FOREIGN CONSTRAINTS</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="coreForeignConstraintsVariable" select="changeSet[addForeignKeyConstraint/@baseTableName=$coreTables]"/>
    <xsl:comment>CORE VIEWS</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="coreViewsVariable" select="changeSet[createView/@viewName=$coreTables]"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="createChangeLog">
      <xsl:with-param name="outputFile" select="'core-changelog.xml'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="changeLogContent" select="$coreTablesVariable,$coreSequencesVariable,$coreIndexesVariable,$coreForeignConstraintsVariable,$coreViewsVariable"/>
    </xsl:call-template>

    <xsl:comment>UNMATCHED</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="unmatchedChangeSets" 
        select="changeSet[not(some $set in ($coreTablesVariable | $coreSequencesVariable | $coreIndexesVariable |$coreForeignConstraintsVariable |$coreViewsVariable) satisfies $set is .)]"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="createChangeLog">
      <xsl:with-param name="outputFile" select="'unmatched-changes-changelog.xml'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="changeLogContent" select="$unmatchedChangeSets"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="createChangeLog">
    <xsl:param name="outputFile"/>
    <xsl:param name="changeLogContent"/>
    <xsl:result-document encoding="UTF-8" indent="true" method="xml" href="{$outputFile}">
      <databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"                                               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                                               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog                                               http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd                                               http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" logicalFilePath="TODO">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$changeLogContent"/>
      </databaseChangeLog>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

I'd like to add to output xml processed inside `createChangelogTemplate` to each element `<changeSet>` another attribute (`context="legacy"`). I was trying to add another template which matches `databaseChangelog/changeSet` with additional `xsl:attribute` element but that didn't worked for me. If is there way how to do this in one place that would be nice, because I will need to prepare more sections like `CORE`.

When I've added template:

```
<xsl:template match="changeSet" mode="legacy">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="context">legacy</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and replaced `<xsl:copy-of select="$changeLogContent"/>` with `<xsl:apply-templates select="$changeLogContent" mode="legacy"/>` then output file `core-changelog.xml` was ok but file `unmatched-changes-changelog.xml` had no elements.

I'm using xslt 2.0 and saxon 9.8he.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this I get changeSets 1 and 1-1 in core-changelog.xml, and changeSet 4 in unmatched-changelog.xml.

If you're still seeing nothing in unmatched-changelog then we need to look in more detail at exactly how you were running it.

Incidentally the selection of unmatched elements could be done as

```
select="changeSet except ($coreTablesVariable | $coreSequencesVariable | $coreIndexesVariable |$coreForeignConstraintsVariable |$coreViewsVariable)"/>
```

Comment: Hi, [this](https://github.com/bilak-poc/saxon-transofmer) is sample project. In project root execute mvn spring-boot:run and it will process template and sample input which are in [resources folder](https://github.com/bilak-poc/saxon-transofmer/tree/master/src/main/resources)

Comment: I'm not going to try running your code because there's too much setup involved. I note that you're using JAXP TransformerHandler which was never designed for use with XSLT 2.0 and `xsl:result-document` and gives you no control over where the output files go; but it shouldn't affect the content of the files. Perhaps you're looking at the wrong output files.

Comment: there is just one step...download the repo with git and invoke `mvn spring-boot:run`. You don't need to install any tool but git. You can handle where the file goes...currently they are moved to root of project.

Comment: That was two steps. That's two steps for you, a lot more for me, because I have to be very careful before I run untrusted code on my development machine.

Comment: Aha these problems in 2018 when there is dependency on saxon and spring-boot library. Really? So what should I prepare for you to be able to look into this problem? Do you want to run it by command line only using saxon?

Comment: We don't treat questions on StackOverflow as formal support requests. If you want to raise a support request with Saxonica please use the proper channels, and please note that our support policy says we require a repro that we can run on the latest Saxon release without any dependencies on third-party libraries that need to be installed. (Even libraries that you imagine everyone is using - it's amazing how many of those there are!)